# chemfig molecule shifts tikzpicture (in beamer)

Tags: tikz-pgf, beamer, chemfig

I have a beamer slide with a title. On it I have a tikzpicture, which contains a molecule drawn with chemfig. Without the molecule the picture is just fine:
[image: mwe1]
However, as soon as I put the molecule, this happens:
[image]
Code:

```
\documentclass[presentation,utf8,t]{beamer}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usepackage{chemfig}
\usetikzlibrary{positioning}

\begin{document}
\begin{frame}
\frametitle{A tikzpicture with some molecules}
\begin{tikzpicture}[scale=0.75]
\draw[gray] (0,0) grid (15,10);
\setcrambond{2pt};
\node[anchor=west] at (4,6) {%
\chemfig[][scale=0.5]{%
(?-[:130]O-[:190](-[:130,0.7]-[:50]OH)-[:-190](-[:190]O-[:-190,,,,dash pattern=on 2pt off 2pt])<[:-50](-[:-190]HO)-[:10,,,,line width=2pt]
?[,{<}](-[:-50,.7]NH-[:-130](=[:180,0.7]O)-[:-50]CH_3))
-[:10]O-[:-10]
?[b]-[:50](-[:190]HO)-[:-10](-[:50,.7]NH-[:130](=[:180,0.7]O)-[:50]CH_3)-[:10](-[:-10,,,,dash pattern=on 2pt off 2pt])<[:-130]O-[:-190,,,,line width=2pt]
?[b,{<}](-[:-130,.7]-[:-50]OH)
}
};
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{frame}
\end{document}
```

Any idea?

Using Texlive via texworks on windows 7

Comment: The culprit part is `\setcrambond{2pt}`. Maybe you can check the manual of `chemfig` for other possibilities of loading this option.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Indeed, the culprit was `\setcrambond`.

It needs the two other options, even though they are empty.
`\setcrambond{2pt}{}{}` is the correct form (adding `;` or not doesn't matter).